# Android: How i can share a link and open an activity when user click on this link

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to make users able to share their objects with others.
I have an activity that can display the object information with an intent filter like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.mywebsite.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

Code for sharing:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_OBJECT_ID, id);
shareIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_IS_LOCAL, false);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.mywebsite.com");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share link using"));
```

But when i click on this link i can not see my application on "Complete action using" dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you trying to send/share the link but you added the intent filter for view in your manifest. So, for view you should set the intent Action to View and then try. Like this:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.mywebsite.com"));
```

This is because you have added the intent filter of view category which is:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

And if you want to share the link then add category of SEND in intent filter like this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
```

I think this will be helpfull for you!

Comment: I want to share the link first as a text then open activity when the user clicks on this link